# About Python ‘backspace’ \b in Jupyterlab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, backspace

When I used '\b' in Jupyterlab, some strange things happened.

When I used one or two '\b', it worked well. However, when I tried more than two '\b', it seems it doesn't work at all.

[image: outcome of my code]

I don't know why. Is it a bug in Jupyterlab, I am confused. Thanks.